# Is there a way to get an image aspect ratio in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, aspect-ratio

Just asking Is there a way to get an image aspect ratio in React?
Let's say you have a bunch of png and jpg files and need to extract the image aspect ratio without manually doing height/width?

Comment: You could try to extract the EXIF data from the image and check if the aspect ratio is there, otherwise, I don't think it is possible. What's the problem of height/width?

Comment: I just have much images 1000+ that need to fit into Mansonry Gallers so would not like to manually adding ratio

Comment: Yes you can. I could extract the metadata from the image with JavaScript, but I don't recommend it, why? It's simple, if you want to reserve the space before rendering to avoid page movement this must be predefined from the beginning in your code.